# How can I stop my textures from becoming low resolution in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using libGDX to make a small game, I made a little [sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmADD.png) (32x32) that is shown in the center of the screen. For some reason when I render the texture to the screen it loses its [quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNvTl.png). Since the textures are so small I made the screen width and height 200 and 100 respectively. Any tips or answers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sprite (32x32) needs to be displayed on an area which is larger than 32x32, meaning that the image needs to be upscaled and *interpolated* (i.e. pixels between the 32 known ones need to be calculated). A common approach is smooth (often times linear) interpolation to fill in the additional pixels, which works well for photorealistic textures; it appears to have occurred here.

For pixel-art, you likely want "nearest-neighbor" interpolation instead. While the exact way to set it depends on the structure of your code, you may be able to do something like:

```
textureObject.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);
```

Comment: do you think you could also tell me how to use filters on an animation nanofarad aswell.

Comment: @playper3 It depends on how your animation is implemented. If you're just animating the transforms of a texture, set the filters on the texture. If it's an animation of TextureRegions, then set the filters on the underlying texture. In general, if the animation is based on an underlying Texture object, you should be able to just set the filter on that Texture object. If something else, then you'll need to clarify the situation a little bit further.

Comment: one final thing if my animation looks like this 'Array<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion> rightFrames = textureAtlas.findRegions("right");' and 'right = new Animation<TextureRegion>(FRAME_DURATION, rightFrames, Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);' where would I put the .setFilter.

Comment: @playper3 How did you *create* the texture atlas? iirc it needs to be set to Nearest-neighbor there, but I don't recall the full details offhand.

Comment: I created the texture atlas like this `textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas("playerSprite.txt");`

Comment: @playper3 `playerSprite.txt` will need to be updated to indicate the appropriate interpolation if I recall correctly. Depending on how you created the file, you may need to re-run the tool that created it.